# Get resource id by name returns "wrong" id

Tags: android

Why the `firstId` is not equal to `secondId`? `firstId` is the wrong one, `secondId` is the correct one.

How can I "force" `getIdentifier` to search for the right `search_button`?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    int firstId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
    int secondId = recursiveLoopChildren(searchView, "search_button").getId();     

    return true;
}

public View recursiveLoopChildren(ViewGroup p_parent, String p_resourceName) {
    View view = null;

    for (int i = p_parent.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final View child = p_parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            View returnedChild = recursiveLoopChildren((ViewGroup) child, p_resourceName);
            if(returnedChild != null) {
                view = returnedChild;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            String entryName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(child.getId());
            if (child != null && entryName.equals(p_resourceName)) {
                view = child;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: This looks like something you should use a debugger for.

Comment: Your basic thinking is flawed, which might be leading you in the wrong direction. `How can I "force" getIdentifier to search for the right search_button`  getIndentifier() works.  You can be sure of this because millions of apps use it millions of times per day without trouble.  If it din't work, it would be a major bug and fixed rapidly since it would essentially stop most apps working at all.  Therefore, your thinking should be "what have I done wrong".  If you look at the source code for getIdentifier(), you will also see how simple it is and inconceivable that it would fail.

Comment: I would start by normalising that for loop. `for (int i = 0 ; i < p_parent.getChildCount() ; i++)`  There is nothing in your code that requires you to iterate backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call getIdentifier() like this:

```
int firstId = getResources().getIdentifier("search_button", "id", getPackageName());
```

Then it should return the correct id.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final View child = p_parent.getChildAt(i - 1);
```

if not works.. try with this condition..

```
for (int i = p_parent.getChildCount(); i > 0; i--)
```

Comment: That method works and outputs the correct view (id). Android core method doesn't.